# PostgreSQL ERROR: function to_tsvector(character varying, unknown) does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, types, casting, full-text-search

This psql session snippet should be self-explanatory:

```
psql (9.1.7)
Type "help" for help.
=> CREATE TABLE languages(language VARCHAR NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE
=> INSERT INTO languages VALUES ('english'),('french'),('turkish');
INSERT 0 3
=> SELECT language, to_tsvector('english', 'hello world') FROM languages;
 language|     to_tsvector     
---------+---------------------
 english | 'hello':1 'world':2
 french  | 'hello':1 'world':2
 turkish | 'hello':1 'world':2
(3 rows)

=> SELECT language, to_tsvector(language, 'hello world') FROM languages;
ERROR:  function to_tsvector(character varying, unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: select language, to_tsvector(language, 'hello world')...
                         ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types.  
You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

The problem is that Postgres function `to_tsvector` doesn't like `varchar` field type but this call should be perfectly correct [according to the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/textsearch-tables.html#TEXTSEARCH-TABLES-INDEX)?

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using?

Comment: What's the datatype of the column `language`? And why do you use the manual for 8.3 if your are using 9.1?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use an explicit type cast:

```
SELECT language, to_tsvector(language::regconfig, 'hello world') FROM languages;
```

Or change the column `languages.language` to type `regconfig`. [See @Swav's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21995741/939860)

#### Why?

Postgres allows [function overloading](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-overload.html). Function signatures are defined by their (optionally *schema*-qualified) *name* plus (the list of) *input parameter type*(s). The 2-parameter form of `to_tsvector()` expects type [**`regconfig`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html) as first parameter:

```sql
SELECT proname, pg_get_function_arguments(oid)
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_proc
WHERE  proname = 'to_tsvector'

   proname   | pg_get_function_arguments
-------------+---------------------------
 to_tsvector | text
 to_tsvector | regconfig, text             -- you are here
```

If no existing function matches *exactly*, the rules of [Function Type Resolution](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/typeconv-func.html) decide the best match - if any. This is successful for  `to_tsvector('english', 'hello world')`, with `'english'` being an **untyped string literal**. But fails with a parameter **typed `varchar`**, because there is no registered *implicit* cast from `varchar` to `regconfig`. [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/typeconv-func.html):

> Discard candidate functions for which the input types do not match and
> cannot be converted (using an **implicit** conversion) to match. **unknown
> literals** are assumed to be convertible to anything for this purpose.

Bold emphasis mine.
The registered casts for `regconfig`:

```sql
SELECT castsource::regtype, casttarget::regtype, castcontext
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_cast
WHERE  casttarget = 'regconfig'::regtype;

 castsource | casttarget | castcontext
------------+------------+-------------
 oid        | regconfig  | i
 bigint     | regconfig  | i
 smallint   | regconfig  | i
 integer    | regconfig  | i
```

[Explanation for `castcontext`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-cast.html)

> `castcontext  char`
> Indicates what contexts the cast can be invoked
> in. `e` means only as an explicit cast (using `CAST` or `::` syntax). `a`
> means implicitly in assignment to a target column, as well as
> explicitly. `i` means implicitly in expressions, as well as the other cases.

Read more about the three different *types of assignment* [in the chapter *"CREATE CAST"*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createcast.html).

Answer (score 3):

#### Alternative approach to Erwin Brandstetter's answer

You could define your language column to be of type regconfig which would make your query a bit less verbose i.e.:

```
CREATE TABLE languages(language regconfig NOT NULL DEFAULT 'english'::regconfig)
```

I have set english as default above, but that's not required. Afterwards your original query

```
SELECT language, to_tsvector(language, 'hello world') FROM languages;
```

would work just fine.