# Function not found in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, types, casting, user-defined-functions, postgresql-11

I have a user-defined function in PostgreSQL 11.2 created as follows. It basically inserts values to two different tables:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.insertTest(
IN ID1 integer, 
IN Value1 character varying,
IN Value2 character varying,
IN Value3 character varying,
IN Status character varying,
IN Active_Flag integer, 
IN Stuff1 smallint,
IN stuff2 smallint)
RETURNS void
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

AS $BODY$
BEGIN

Insert into TableA 
(TA_ID,
 TA_Value1, 
 TA_Value2,
 TA_Value3, 
 TA_Value4,
 TA_Time, 
 TA_Flag)
values 
(ID1,
 Value1, 
 Value2,
 Value3, 
 Status,
 now(), 
 1);

Insert into TableB
(TA_ID,
 TB_ID,      Confidence,     Sev_Rate, 
 Last_Update_Time,   TB_Flag)
values
(currval('tablea_t_id_seq'), --TableA has an auto-increment field
 Active_Flag,    Stuff1,     Stuff2,
 now(), 
 0);

END;
$BODY$;
```

Now when I try to execute this function, the following does not works:

```
SELECT * FROM public.insertTest (
550, 'Test_Value1', 
'Test_Value2', 'Test_Value3', 
'DEL', 55, 1, 1)
```

and throws this error:

> ```
> ERROR:  function insertTest(integer, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, integer, integer, integer) does not exist
> LINE 1: select insertTest(550,'Test_Value1', 'Test_...
>                ^
> HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
> ```

But the following works:

```
SELECT * FROM public.insertTest (
550::integer, 'Test_Value1'::character varying, 
'Test_Value2'::character varying, 'Test_Value3'::character varying, 
'DEL'::character varying, 55::integer, 1::smallint, 1::smallint);
```

Can someone tell me why the 1st execution of the function does not work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ... why the 1st execution of the function does not work?

The exact answer is: [**Function Type Resolution**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/typeconv-func.html).

The `varchar` columns are *not* the problem (unlike another answer suggests). **String literals** like `'Test_Value1'` (with single quotes) are initially type `unknown` and there is an implicit conversion to `varchar` for that.

The `int2` columns at the end are the "problem" (or rather, the mismatched input for those). **Numeric literals** like `1` (without quotes!) are initially assumed to be type `integer`. And there is **no implicit cast** from `integer` (`int4`) to `smallint` (`int2`). See:

```sql
SELECT castsource::regtype, casttarget::regtype, castcontext
FROM   pg_cast
WHERE  castsource = 'int'::regtype
AND    casttarget = 'int2'::regtype;
```

Reveals `castcontext = 'a'`. [The manual about `castcontext`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-cast.html)

> `e` means only as an explicit cast (using `CAST` or `::` syntax). `a` means implicitly in assignment to a target column, as well as explicitly. `i` means implicitly in expressions, as well as the other cases

With an explicit cast, the function call succeeds:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_temp.insertTest (
550, 'Test_Value1', 
'Test_Value2', 'Test_Value3', 
'DEL', 55, int2 '1', int2 '1');
```

Or even just:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_temp.insertTest (
550, 'Test_Value1', 
'Test_Value2', 'Test_Value3', 
'DEL', 55,  '1', '1');
```

Now, with added quotes, those are *string literals*, initially type `unknown`, and there is an implicit conversion to `int2` for those.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yWHSpxLc)

Closely related, with step-by-step explanation:

- [No function matches the given name and argument types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24751372/no-function-matches-the-given-name-and-argument-types/24771122#24771122)
- [Is there a way to disable function overloading in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28698641/is-there-a-way-to-disable-function-overloading-in-postgres/28710225#28710225)

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the error message, PostgreSQL expects that you call `function insertTest(integer, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, integer, integer, integer)`. All parameters of type *character varying* are not regarded as such and therefore the inputs will be cast to `unknown`.

You'll find an adequate explanation in [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42975780/postgres-string-is-being-cast-as-unknown) (look at the comments). Fortunately, you already have a potential solution by providing type declarations explicitly, at least for your *character varying* parameters.