# Deserialize text to record

Tags: sql, postgresql, types, row

Lets say we have table `post` with some rows in it:

```sql
create table post(
  id serial primary key,
  title text not null,
  body text not null,
  created_at timestamp not null 
);
```

We can select a subset of those columns as a `row` type like this:

```
select row(id, title) as foo from post;
```

```
  foo::record
----------------
(1, "First Post")
```

We can serialize that to text easily:

```
select row(id, title)::text as foo from post;
```

```
    foo::text
------------------
'(1, "First Post")'
```

How can that text then be deserialized back into a `row(int,text)`?
Something like (pseudo-code):

```
select '(1,"First Post")'::row(int,text)  -- not valid
```

Comment: Which of these do you need to extract: name / type / value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core of the problem is this: a [**ROW constructor**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS) like you have there produces an [**anonymous record** (a pseudo-type)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-pseudo.html), which preserves nested original *values* as original data types, but loses the meta information on *names* and *data types*.

Original values are still in there (not just as `unknown` or `text`). The ROW value is notably more than its text representation, the row *literal* `(1, "First Post")`, which is stripped of almost all type information. But Postgres demands the "ingredient list" up front to expand a record to individual fields (or a row to individual columns).

When dealing with well-known row types (named types from tables, views, subqueries, registered composite types etc.) this meta information is retrieved from catalog tables ([`pg_attribute`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-attribute.html) at its core). To expand an anonymous record, you need to provide the information *somehow*.

The **simple way is to *cast* to a named row/composite type** - which also works for the row literal. Postgres fetches required meta information from said catalog tables. That's what [Gordon's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59585967/939860) with `CREATE TYPE` does. Then you can expand the row with simple `*` syntax to get individual fields:

```
CREATE TYPE foo_type AS (id int, title text);
```

Extract fields after casting:

```
SELECT ('(1,"First Post")'::foo_type).*;       -- for row literal input
SELECT (ROW(id, title)::foo_type).* FROM post; -- for actual record input
```

**But** you are trying to ...

> **avoid creating a bunch of composites**

If you just don't want to create composite types explicitly - any registered row type from a table or view is good for it:

```
CREATE VIEW foo_view AS SELECT id, title FROM post;
SELECT ('(1,"First Post")'::foo_view).*;
```

Even `TEMPORARY` objects would do:

```
CREATE TEMP VIEW foo_view AS ...
```

Still registers the row type, but only the current session can see it.

Finally, there are even ways without additional registered row type:

#### 1. Use row type derived from underlying table(s)

```
SELECT foo.* FROM (SELECT id, title FROM post) foo;
```

Note the **subquery** instead of a ROW constructor. This allows Postgres to look up fields in the underlying table(s).

#### 2. Use a dummy function returning `record` with a target definition list.

This is advanced stuff. Functions can return anonymous records. You must provide a [**column definition list**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS) to expand rows. Rarely useful. This is one of the rare cases. But Postgres does not allow `record` as function *input* parameter:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_expand_record(record)
  RETURNS record LANGUAGE sql AS
'SELECT $1';
```

> ```
> ERROR:  SQL functions cannot have arguments of type record
> ```

We can resort to polymorphic input, which circumvents this limitation:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_expand_record(anyelement)
  RETURNS record LANGUAGE sql AS
'SELECT $1';
```

Now `ROW` input is possible:

```
SELECT * FROM f_expand_record(ROW(1,text 'First Post')) AS t(id int, title text);
```

But a *row literal* is not, as polymorphic functions demand typed input:

```
SELECT * FROM f_expand_record('(1,"First Post")') AS t(id int, title text);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=28d6d6b5a2778d3136e61c6edca6c20a)*

Comment: My (incorrect) use of row and record interchangeably confused things a bit. The main goal is to cast from a text representation of an anonymous record, back to an anonymous record. From your explanation, it seems like that isn't possible without first registering a concrete type via creating a composite/view/etc (please correct me if that isn't right). I hoped something like 

`select * from (select id, title from post) foo where foo = '(1,"First Post")'::foo`

or a cte might temporarily register a foo type that could be used for casting, but no such luck! 
Great response
Thanks!

Comment: @OliverRice: Sounds like you got everything right. Like the error message in this [additional fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=50e557fc191881741ad35e75c24ce2eb) informs (and you have probably seen yourself by now): `ERROR:  input of anonymous composite types is not implemented`. This will likely *never* work, because the row *literal* does not contain any type information - which anonymous records still carry, as explained above. But check out the additional fiddle, I added a few more potentially useful bits.

Comment: Hi. @ErwinBrandstetter   `SELECT * FROM f_expand_record(ROW(1,'first post'::text)) AS t(id int, title text); `is same as `SELECT * FROM f_expand_record(ROW(1,text 'First Post')) AS t(id int, title text);` the **text** is important in here. However int I don't explicit mention int. Can you further explain or just drop a link about the **text** usage in this context.

Comment: @Mark: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13676871/939860 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/24771122/939860

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a way to create types on the fly.  You can do this with an explicit type cast:

```
create type x AS (a int, b text);

select '(1,"First Post")'::x
```

Comment: thanks. I'm trying to avoid creating a bunch of composites