# Is there a way to disable function overloading in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, types, casting, plpgsql, postgresql-9.3

My users and I do not use function overloading in PL/pgSQL. We always have one function per (schema, name) tuple. As such, we'd like to drop a function by name only, change its signature without having to drop it first, etc. Consider for example, the following function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunc(day_number SMALLINT)
RETURNS TABLE(a INT)
AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY (SELECT 1 AS a);
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

To save time, we would like to invoke it as follows, without qualifying 1 with `::SMALLINT`, because there is only one function named myfunc, and it has exactly one parameter named day_number:

```
SELECT * FROM myfunc(day_number := 1)
```

There is no ambiguity, and the value 1 is consistent with `SMALLINT` type, yet PostgreSQL complains:

```
SELECT * FROM myfunc(day_number := 1);
```

> ```
> ERROR:  function myfunc(day_number := integer) does not exist
> LINE 12: SELECT * FROM myfunc(day_number := 1);
>                        ^
> HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types.
> You might need to add explicit type casts.
> ```

When we invoke such functions from Python, we use a wrapper that looks up functions' signatures and qualifies parameters with types. This approach works, but there seems to be a potential for improvement.

Is there a way to turn off function overloading altogether?

Comment: PostgreSQL uses strong typing - and it should be respected. When your function is defined with smallint, it cannot be called with int. If you don't would to solve types - use a most generic types in function parameters. In this case integer instead smallint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually not directly a matter of function overloading (which would be impossible to "turn off"). It's a matter of **function type resolution**. (Of course, that algorithm could be more permissive without overloaded functions.)

All of these would just work:

```
SELECT * FROM myfunc(day_number := '1');
SELECT * FROM myfunc('1');               -- note the quotes

SELECT * FROM myfunc(1::smallint);
SELECT * FROM myfunc('1'::smallint);
```

### Why?

The last two are rather obvious, you mentioned that in your question already.
The first two are more interesting, the explanation is buried in the [**Function Type Resolution**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/typeconv-func.html):

> unknown literals are assumed to be convertible to anything for this purpose.

And that should be the **simple solution** for you: **use string literals**.

An untyped literal `'1'` (with quotes) or "string literal" as defined in the SQL standard is different in nature from a *typed* literal (or constant).

A numeric constant `1` (without quotes) is cast to a numeric type *immediately*. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS-NUMERIC)

> A numeric constant that contains neither a decimal point nor an
>   exponent is **initially presumed to be type integer** if its value fits in
>   type `integer` (32 bits); otherwise it is presumed to be type `bigint` if
>   its value fits in type `bigint` (64 bits); otherwise it is taken to be
>   type `numeric`. Constants that contain decimal points and/or exponents
>   are always initially presumed to be type `numeric`.
>
> The initially assigned data type of a numeric constant is just a
>   starting point for the type resolution algorithms. In most cases the
>   constant will be automatically coerced to the most appropriate type
>   depending on context. When necessary, you can force a numeric value to
>   be interpreted as a specific data type by casting it.

Bold emphasis mine.

The assignment in the function call (`day_number := 1`) is a special case, the data type of `day_number` is *unknown* at this point. Postgres cannot derive a data type from this assignment and defaults to `integer`.

Consequently, Postgres looks for a function taking an `integer` *first*. Then for functions taking a type only an **implicit cast** away from `integer`, in other words:

```
SELECT casttarget::regtype
FROM   pg_cast
WHERE  castsource = 'int'::regtype
AND    castcontext = 'i';
```

All of these would be found - and conflict if there were more than one function.  ***That would be function overloading***, and you would get a different error message. With two candidate functions like this:

```
SELECT * FROM myfunc(1);
```

> ```
> ERROR:  function myfunc(integer) is not unique
> ```

Note the "integer" in the message: the numeric constant has been cast to `integer`.

However, the cast from `integer` to `smallint` is "only" an **assignment cast**. And that's where the journey ends:

> ```
> No function matches the given name and argument types.
> ```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d41d8/2868)

More detailed explanation in these related answers:

- [PostgreSQL ERROR: function to_tsvector(character varying, unknown) does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523624/postgresql-error-function-to-tsvectorcharacter-varying-unknown-does-not-exis/14524599#14524599)
- [Generate series of dates - using date type as input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21045909/generate-series-of-dates-using-date-type-as-input/21051215#21051215)

#### Dirty fix

You ***could*** fix this by "upgrading" the cast from `integer` to `smallint` to an **implicit cast**:

```
UPDATE pg_cast
SET    castcontext = 'i'
WHERE  castsource = 'int'::regtype
AND    casttarget  = 'int2'::regtype;
```

But I would **strongly discourage** tampering with the default casting system. Only consider this if you know exactly what you are doing. You'll find related discussions in the Postgres lists. It can have all kinds of side effects, starting with function type resolution, but not ending there.

#### Aside

Function type resolution is completely independent from the used language. An SQL function would compete with PL/perl or PL/pgSQL or "internal" functions just the same. The function signature is essential. Built-in functions only come first, because `pg_catalog` comes first in the default `search_path`.

Comment: yes, the main problem is casting, not overloading in this case.

Comment: This is highly useful, especially the following: "Function type resolution is completely independent from the used language". IMO it should be added to the documentation.

Answer (score 8):

Erwin sent a correct reply. My next reply is related to possibility to disable overloading.

It is not possible to disable overloading - this is a base feature of PostgreSQL function API system - and cannot be disabled. We know so there are some side effects like strong function signature rigidity - but it is protection against some unpleasant side effects when function is used in Views, table definitions, .. So you cannot to disable it.

You can simply check if you have or have not overloaded functions:

```
postgres=# select count(*), proname 
               from pg_proc 
              where pronamespace <> 11 
              group by proname 
              having count(*) > 1;
 count | proname 
-------+---------
(0 rows)
```

Comment: Thank you Pavel. We'll add this check to our test harness. Currently our system is smallish, and getting duplicates is unlikely, but it could grow later on.

Comment: @AlexC: If this query finds duplicate names, you *may* have issues with overloaded function names - but only if more than one function of the same name is actually in your current [`search_path`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-to-create-table-inside-specific-schema-by-default-in-postgres/9067777#9067777) (while not schema-qualifying the function call) or if more than one reside in the given schema, and the function signature can actually conflict.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - the real searching of really overloaded functions is little bit complex, but if you are worry about overloading, then this simple check is accurate. Overloading is good if you can use it, and terrible ugly if you forgot it. Personally, I don't afraid about overloading - with full sets of regress tests and explicit management of code with procedures - I edit SP in files and I deploy these files.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of in built functions that are overloaded, so it simply would not work if you turned off function overloading.

Comment: Are these built in functions developed in LANGUAGE PlPgSql? What if I could turn overloading on and off as a session setting, like isolation level?

Comment: The problem is you would run into functions where you would not be able to invoke them (which of the functions with same name, but different parameter types would you call?). Either way - it is not possible.

Comment: Another possible idea you could try would be to change the argument type to integer, and then cast it in the function definition. Without having any data to support this, I would guess you wouldn't hit much of a performance penalty.