# Postgres: How to store bytea as value in hstore?

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting, postgresql-9.3, hstore

I am trying to store a `bytea` as a value in `hstore` and I keep getting the following error:

> ```
> function hstore(unknown, bytea) does not exist
> ```

Here is what I have tried:

```
UPDATE users set store = store || hstore('key1', pgp_pub_encrypt('testval',dearmor('xxxx')));
```

Answer (score 2):

> am trying to store a bytea as a value in hstore

You cannot safely store `bytea` in `hstore` without some kind of encoding, because `hstore` is stored as text in the current text encoding, but `bytea` has no text encoding and may also contain null bytes that are not legal in text strings.

So you need to encode the bytea as hex, base64, or some other form that makes it into valid text in the current encoding.

The simplest way is to cast it to `text`, but I recommend instead using `encode` and `decode` to/from base64. This encoding is more compact than the `text` or `hex` encodings used for `bytea`'s text representation in PostgreSQL, and it's also independent of the value of the `bytea_output` setting.

e.g.

```
UPDATE users
SET store = store
    || hstore('key1', encode( pgp_pub_encrypt('testval',dearmor('xxxx'))), 'base64')
WHERE ... ;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two variants of the [**`hstore()`** function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/hstore.html#HSTORE-FUNC-TABLE) taking arrays, one taking a row / record and one taking **two `text` values**. The last one is for you:

```
SELECT hstore('foo','abc'::bytea::text);  -- cast bytea to text!
```

Your attempt failed the rules of function type resolution because there is **no *explicit* cast** registered from `bytea` to `text`. Postgres falls back to input / output conversion for that, which does not count for function type resolution:

- [Is there a way to disable function overloading in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28698641/is-there-a-way-to-disable-function-overloading-in-postgres/28710225#28710225)

So:

```
UPDATE users
SET    store = store
        || hstore('key1', pgp_pub_encrypt('testval',dearmor('xxxx'))::text)
WHERE ... ;
```