# PostgreSQL: Create index on length of all table fields

Tags: performance, postgresql, database-performance, database-indexes

I have a table called `profile`, and I want to order them by which ones are the most filled out. Each of the columns is either a JSONB column or a TEXT column.  I don't need this to a great degree of certainty, so typically I've ordered as follow:

```
SELECT * FROM profile ORDER BY LENGTH(CONCAT(profile.*)) DESC;
```

However, this is slow, and so I want to create an index. However, this does not work:

```
CREATE INDEX index_name ON profile (LENGTH(CONCAT(*))
```

Nor does

```
CREATE INDEX index_name ON profile (LENGTH(CONCAT(CAST(* AS TEXT))))
```

Can't say I'm surprised.  What is the right way to declare this index?

Comment: "does not work" is a poor description of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

To measure the size of the row in text representation you can just cast the whole row to text, which is much faster than concatenating individual columns:

```
SELECT length(profile::text) FROM profile;
```

But there are 3 (or 4) issues with this expression in an index:

1. The syntax shorthand `profile::text` is not accepted in `CREATE INDEX`, you need to add extra parentheses or default to the standard syntax `cast(profile AS text)`
2. Still the same problem that [@jjanes already discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34143582/939860): only `IMMUTABLE` functions are allowed in index expressions and casting a row type to `text` does not pass this requirement. You could build a fake `IMMUTABLE` wrapper function, like Jeff outlined.
3. There is an inherent **ambiguity** (that applies to Jeff's answer as well!): if you have a column name that's the same as the table name (which is a common case) you cannot reference the row type in `CREATE INDEX` since the identifier always resolves to the column name first.
4. Minor difference to your original: This adds column separators, row decorators and possibly escape characters to the `text` representation. Shouldn't matter much to your use case.

**However**, I would suggest a more radical alternative as crude indicator for the size of a row: [**`pg_column_size()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-DBSIZE). Even shorter and faster and avoids issues *1*, *3* and *4*:

```
SELECT pg_column_size(profile) FROM profile;
```

Issue *2* remains, though: `pg_column_size()` is also only `STABLE`. You can create a simple and cheap SQL wrapper function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_column_size(profile)
  RETURNS int LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
'SELECT pg_catalog.pg_column_size($1)';
```

and then proceed like @jjanes outlined. More details:

- [Does PostgreSQL support "accent insensitive" collations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005036/does-postgresql-support-accent-insensitive-collations/11007216#11007216)

Note that I created the function with the row type `profile` as parameter. Postgres allows function overloading, which is why we can use the same function name. Now, when we feed the matching row type to `pg_column_size()` our custom function matches more closely according to **[function type resolution](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/typeconv-func.html)** rules and is picked instead of the polymorphic system function. Alternatively, use a separate name and possibly make the function polymorphic as well ...

Related:

- [Is there a way to disable function overloading in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28698641/is-there-a-way-to-disable-function-overloading-in-postgres/28710225#28710225)

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a function which is falsely marked "immutable" and build an index on that.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION len_immut(record)
 RETURNS int
 LANGUAGE plperl
 IMMUTABLE
AS $function$
  ## This function lies about its immutability.
  ## Use it with care.  It is useful for indexing
  ## entire table rows.
  return length(join ",", values %{$_[0]});
$function$
```

and then

```
create index on profile (len_immut(profile));

SELECT * FROM profile ORDER BY len_immut(profile) DESC;
```

Since the function is falsely labelled as `immutable`, the index may become out of date if you do things like add or drop columns on the table, or change the types of columns.