# PostgreSQL function call

Tags: postgresql, function, types, casting

I have PostgreSQL function named `test(integer)` taking an `integer` parameter and an overloaded function of the same name `test(character varying)`.

When calling this function with a null value, Postgres always executes the function taking an `integer` parameter. Why does this happen? Why doesn't Postgres chose the function with a `varchar` parameter?

Function call example:

```
select test(null);
```

Comment: What's your exact Postgres version and which client do you use for the test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's decided by the rules of [**Function Type Resolution**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/typeconv-func.html). Detailed explanation in the manual. Related:

- [Is there a way to disable function overloading in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28698641/is-there-a-way-to-disable-function-overloading-in-postgres/28710225#28710225)

NULL without explicit type cast starts out as type "unknown":

```
SELECT pg_typeof(NULL)

 pg_typeof
-----------
 unknown
```

**Actually,** I got suspicious and ran a quick test, just to find different results in Postgres 9.3 and 9.4. `varchar` is picked over `integer` (which ***oddly*** contradicts your findings):

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d5281/1)

I would think the according rule is [point 4e in the list](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/typeconv-func.html) (none of the earlier points decide the match):

> At each position, select the string category if any candidate accepts
>   that category. (This bias towards string is appropriate since an
>   unknown-type literal looks like a string.)

If you added another function with input type `text` to the overloaded mix, `text` would be picked over `varchar`.

Personally I *almost always* use `text` instead of `varchar`. While being binary compatible (so almost but not quite the same), `text` is closer to the heart of Postgres in every respect.

I added that to the fiddle, as well as another example where Postgres cannot decide and throws a tantrum.

If you want to pick a particular function, add an explicit type cast (that's the way to go here!):

```
select test(null::int)     AS func_int
     , test(null::varchar) AS func_vc;
```