# How to solve a error 42883 in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, types, casting, plpgsql

When I run this script:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION registeruser(character varying, character varying, money, character varying, character varying, date)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
INSERT INTO "Users"("Name", "Surnames", "Money", "Email", "Password", "UserType", "State", "BirthDate")
VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,'Costumer','Active',$6);

END;
$BODY$  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;

SELECT RegisterUser('Andrea','Gianchero',0,'gian@hotmail.com','rome','1960-04-12');
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR:  function registeruser(unknown, unknown, integer, unknown, unknown, unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT RegisterUser('Andrea','Gianchero',0,'gian@hotmail.com...
             ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Your InitCaps / CamelCase looks suspect.

Comment: Postgres won't automatically convert integers to `money`. You need to cast it yourself.

Answer (score 4):

A string literal such as `'Andrea'` is untyped and is **not** the same as a parameter of type `varchar`. Test the following two lines in your psql console:

```
select 'Andrea';
select 'Andrea'::character varying;
```

The first will output `Andrea` with default column name `?column?`
the second will output `Andrea` but with column name `varchar`. From the documentation:

> The notations varchar(n) and char(n) are aliases for character varying(n) and character(n), respectively.

To solve your problem, simply cast all the string literals in your function call to type `varchar` (or `character varying`). Also, the `0` should be cast to type `money`, at the moment it is recognized as an `integer`:

```
SELECT RegisterUser('Andrea'::varchar, 'Gianchero'::varchar, 0::money,...)
```

Comment: I already do but it dosen't solve the problem ERROR:  function registeruser(unknown, unknown, money, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT registeruser('Alfonso','Gianchero',0::money,'gian@gma...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: @Francisco: did you also cast the integer value to `money` as nick barnes wrote in his comment?

Comment: @Francisco: The error message in your comment indicates *8* parameters while your function has *6*. Remove the trailing parameters and it should work. This is a matter of [Function Type Resolution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34324169/939860).

Comment: `?column?` is not a data type, but the default column name. Unless there is function overloading, only `money` requires a cast, since there is no implicit cast defined. It would be better to cast the string literal directly: `money '0'`

Comment: Casting the input resolved my issue with this. What I found odd was that using a varchar string with `'<value>'` worked in a previously ran procedure, but for the newest one it didn't work unless I casted it with `::character varying` which I guess I could have shortened to `::varchar`.