# Altering Enum type in Postgres gets 42883 error

Tags: postgresql, enums

I'm trying to rollback an addition that was made to this Enum named group_type in Postgres that was made to a column named type on my table groups.

In Postgress I've run,

```
ALTER TYPE group_type RENAME TO group_type_old;
CREATE TYPE group_type AS ENUM ('public', 'private');
ALTER TABLE groups ALTER COLUMN type DROP DEFAULT;
ALTER TABLE groups ALTER COLUMN "type" TYPE group_type USING "type"::text::group_type;
```

And I get the following error on the last statement,

```
Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  operator does not exist: text = group_type_old
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Any ideas what the issue is with my last statement?

Comment: If you hadn't gone down the denormalization road, you could have solved that with a simple DELETE statement.

Comment: Which part is denormalizing or repeating data? The column was named "type" before I started working with this DB, which is also a keyword. Could that be part of the issue?

Comment: Using an enum is de-normalizing

Comment: What version of Postgres? Is it the community version of Postgres or a fork say AWS? In what client are you running the code?  **Add answers as update to question.**

Comment: It's a local version of Postgres using 12.3, and it gets the same error running a migration through an Elixir app and with using the TablePlus application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You code works as intended. Even no problem in Postgresql 9.6!

- [Postgresql 14 demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=7a32c0d6a472b556f01a092ded799bc0)
- [Postgresql 9.6 demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=569276b78a0a4a77ec1cdffbf8c82585)
  I generally wrapped it in a transaction.

  `begin;`
  `ALTER TYPE group_type RENAME TO group_type_old;`
  `CREATE TYPE group_type AS ENUM ('sad', 'ok','happy','happy1');`
  `ALTER TABLE groups ALTER COLUMN type DROP DEFAULT;`
  `ALTER TABLE groups ALTER COLUMN "type" TYPE group_type USING "type"::text::group_type;`
  `drop type group_type_old;`
  `commit;`

Comment: Using Postgres 12.3 and the error comes up using a migration through an Elixir app and through the application TablePlus. I tried the demo app you posted with Postgres 12 and it seems to run fine too, anything else I could potentially check for an issue that you know of?

Comment: You can also copy your partial data to dbfilddle uk to test. If data test ok, then check other table related object.

Comment: google search. I  get https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35188497/how-to-solve-a-error-42883-in-postgres maybe helpful to you. @WilliamRoss

Comment: @WilliamRoss wait.  What's the original enum  element.

Comment: Original Enum was created as: CREATE TYPE group_type AS ENUM ('public', 'private'). 

Found a hackish rollback workaround that is good enough for now. Giving you the bounty for the help, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

For what it's worth; I ran into this error when a value from the old enum was still mentioned as a CHECK constraint in my table, which also had the enum in a column.
I solved it by dropping the constraint, changing the enum, then adding the (updated) constraint again.