# PostgreSQL ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "1e+06"

Tags: postgresql, function, casting, integer, plr

The full error message is:

> ```
> ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "1e+06"
> SQL state: 22P02
> Context: In PL/R function sample
> ```

The query I'm using is:

```
WITH a as
(
 SELECT a.tract_id_alias,
     array_agg(a.pgid ORDER BY a.pgid) as pgids,
     array_agg(a.sample_weight_geo ORDER BY a.pgid) as block_weights
 FROM results_20161109.block_microdata_res_joined a
 WHERE a.tract_id_alias in (66772, 66773, 66785, 66802, 66805, 66806, 66813)
 AND a.bldg_count_res > 0 
 GROUP BY a.tract_id_alias

)
SELECT NULL::INTEGER agent_id, 
     a.tract_id_alias,
     b.year,
    unnest(shared.sample(a.pgids, 
                       b.n_agents, 
                       1 * b.year, 
                       True, 
                       a.block_weights)
                       ) as pgid
FROM a
LEFT JOIN results_20161109.initial_agent_count_by_tract_res_11 b
ON a.tract_id_alias = b.tract_id_alias
ORDER BY b.year, a.tract_id_alias, pgid;
```

And the `shared.sample` function I'm using is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION shared.sample(ids bigint[], size integer, seed integer DEFAULT 1, with_replacement boolean DEFAULT false, probabilities numeric[] DEFAULT NULL::numeric[])
  RETURNS integer[] AS
$BODY$
    set.seed(seed)
    if (length(ids) == 1) {
        s = rep(ids,size)
    } else {
        s = sample(ids,size, with_replacement,probabilities)
    }
    return(s)
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plr VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION shared.sample(bigint[], integer, integer, boolean, numeric[])
  OWNER TO "server-superusers";
```

I'm pretty new to this stuff, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should [edit] your question with relevant information: what you commented below, your version of Postgres, the current schema search path (`SHOW search_path`) and table definitions showing relevant data types.

Answer (score 5):

Not a problem of the function. Like the error messages says: The string `'1e+06'` cannot be cast to `integer`.

Obviously, the columns `n_agents` in your table `results_20161109.initial_agent_count_by_tract_res_11` is not an `integer` column. Probably type `text` or `varchar`? (That info would help in your question.)

Either way, the assignment cast does not work for the target type `integer`. But it does for `numeric`:

Does not work:

```
SELECT '1e+06'::text::int;  -- error as in question
```

Works:

```
SELECT '1e+06'::text::numeric::int;
```

If my assumptions hold, you can use this as stepping stone.
Replace `b.n_agents` in your query with **`b.n_agents::numeric::int`**.

It's your responsibility that numbers stay in integer range, or you get the next exception.

---

If that did not nail it, you need to look into **function overloading**:

- [Is there a way to disable function overloading in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28698641/is-there-a-way-to-disable-function-overloading-in-postgres/28710225#28710225)

And **function type resolution**:

- [PostgreSQL function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34323469/postgresql-function-call/34324169#34324169)

The schema search path is relevant in many related cases, but you did schema-qualify all objects, so we can rule that out.

- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the "current schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-does-the-search-path-influence-identifier-resolution-and-the-current-schema/9067777#9067777)

**Your query** generally looks good. I had a look and only found minor improvements:

```
SELECT NULL::int AS agent_id  -- never omit the AS keyword for column alias
     , a.tract_id_alias
     , b.year
     , s.pgid
FROM  (
   SELECT tract_id_alias
        , array_agg(pgid)              AS pgids
        , array_agg(sample_weight_geo) AS block_weights
   FROM  (  -- use a subquery, cheaper than CTE
      SELECT tract_id_alias
           , pgid
           , sample_weight_geo
      FROM   results_20161109.block_microdata_res_joined
      WHERE  tract_id_alias IN (66772, 66773, 66785, 66802, 66805, 66806, 66813)
      AND    bldg_count_res > 0
      ORDER  BY pgid  -- sort once in a subquery. cheaper.
      ) sub
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) a
LEFT   JOIN results_20161109.initial_agent_count_by_tract_res_11 b USING (tract_id_alias)
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL
   unnest(shared.sample(a.pgids
                      , b.n_agents
                      , b.year  -- why "1 * b.year"?
                      , true
                      , a.block_weights)) s(pgid) ON true
ORDER  BY b.year, a.tract_id_alias, s.pgid;
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I tried it out and am still getting the same error. The `n_agents` column in `results_20161109.initial_agent_count_by_tract_res_11` is indeed of type `integer`, so I'm not sure what else the problem could be.

Comment: So I noticed there are several `shared.sample` functions in the `shared` schema, each doing the same thing and using the same R function, but taking different base types as the arguments, e.g.:

`sample(integer[], integer, bigint, boolean, numeric[])`
`sample(integer[], integer, integer, boolean, numeric[])`
`sample(bigint[], integer, bigint, boolean, numeric[])`
`sample(bigint[], integer, integer, boolean, numeric[])`

Could this be affecting the results?

Comment: @KevinM: Yes, it can. I added some hints above.