# Query jsonb array for integer member

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, jsonb, paper-trail-gem, postgresql-9.6

Background: We use PaperTrail to keep the history of our changing models. Now I want to query for a Item, which belonged to a certain customer. PaperTrail optionally stores the `object_changes` and I need to query this field to understand, when something was created with this ID or changed to this ID.

My table looks simplified like this:

```
item_type | object_changes
----------|----------------------------------------------------------
"Item"    | {"customer_id": [null, 5], "other": [null, "change"]}
"Item"    | {"customer_id": [4, 5], "other": ["unrelated", "change"]}
"Item"    | {"customer_id": [5, 6], "other": ["asht", "asht"]}
```

How do I query for elements changed from or to ID 5 (so all rows above)? I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM versions WHERE object_changes->'customer_id' ? 5;
```

Which got me:

> ```
> ERROR:  operator does not exist: jsonb ? integer
> LINE 1: ...T * FROM versions WHERE object_changes->'customer_id' ? 5;
>                                                                  ^
> HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s).
> You might need to add explicit type casts.
> ```

Comment: You might also like the `where_object_changes` method. It's supposed to be a convenient way to do a `where` clause for the `object_changes` column.

Comment: So do you have your answer?

Answer (score 7):

For **`jsonb`** the [contains operator **`@>`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) does what you ask for:

*Get all rows where the number **5** is an element of the "customer_id" array:*

```
SELECT *
FROM   versions 
WHERE  object_changes->'customer_id' @> '5';
```

The `@>` operator expects `jsonb` as right operand - or a string literal that is valid for `jsonb` (while `?` expects `text`). The numeric literal *without single quotes* you provided in your example (`5`) cannot be coerced to `jsonb` (nor `text`), it defaults to `integer`. Hence the error message. Related:

- [No function matches the given name and argument types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24751372/no-function-matches-the-given-name-and-argument-types/24771122#24771122)
- [PostgreSQL ERROR: function to_tsvector(character varying, unknown) does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523624/postgresql-error-function-to-tsvectorcharacter-varying-unknown-does-not-exis/14524599#14524599)

This can be supported with different **index styles**. For my query suggested  above, use an expression index (specialized, small and fast):

```
CREATE INDEX versions_object_changes_customer_id_gin_idx ON versions
USING gin ((object_changes->'customer_id'));
```

This alternative query works, too:

```
SELECT * FROM versions WHERE object_changes @> '{"customer_id": [5]}';
```

And can be supported with a general index (more versatile, bigger, slower):

```
CREATE INDEX versions_object_changes_gin_idx ON versions
USING gin (object_changes jsonb_path_ops);
```

Related:

- [Index for finding an element in a JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404055/index-for-finding-an-element-in-a-json-array/18405706#18405706)
- [Query for array elements inside JSON type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736742/query-for-array-elements-inside-json-type/22737710#22737710)

[According to the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE), the operator **`?`** searches for any `top-level key within the JSON value`. Testing indicates that **strings** in arrays are considered *"top-level keys"*, but **numbers** are ***not*** (keys have to be strings after all). So while this query would work:

```
SELECT * FROM versions WHERE object_changes->'other' ? 'asht';
```

Your query looking for a *number* in an array will not (even when you quote the input string literal properly). It would only find the (quoted!) string `"5"`, classified as *key*, but not the (unquoted) number `5`, classified as *value*.

Aside: [Standard JSON only knows 4 primitives](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159): *string*, *number*, *boolean* and *null*. There is no *integer* primitive (even if I have heard of software adding that), *integer* is a just a subset of *number*, which is implemented as `numeric` in Postgres:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html#JSON-TYPE-MAPPING-TABLE

So your question title is slightly misleading as there are no "integer" members, strictly speaking.

Answer (score 1):

Use a lateral join and the `jsonb_array_elements_text` function to process each row's `object_changes`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT v.* FROM versions v
JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements_text(v.object_changes->'customer_id') ids ON TRUE
WHERE ids.value::int = 5;
```

The `DISTINCT` is only necessary if the `customer_id` you're looking for could appear multiple times in the array (if a different field changed but `customer_id` is tracked anyway).