# Creating GIN index throws "function does not exist" error

Tags: postgresql, indexing, full-text-search

My table has the following columns:

- content_vector tsvector
- lang VARCHAR(50)

I'm struggling with creating a GIN index.

### Approach one: Explicit type casting

```
CREATE INDEX pages_vector_ix ON pages USING GIN (to_tsvector(lang::regconfig, content_vector));
```

This creates the following error despite using an explicit type cast as described [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14524599/3255061):

```
function to_tsvector(regconfig, tsvector) does not exist
```

### Approach two: Altering column's type

It should also be possible to change the column type to *reconfig* [according to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21995741/3255061):

```
ALTER TABLE pages ALTER COLUMN lang TYPE reconfig USING lang::reconfig;
```

Now I'm getting an error because apparently I've stored languages in the database that can't be used as a text search configuration, for example:

```
text search configuration "afrikaans" does not exist
```

**This error makes me question if it's possible to set a GIN index at all if there are potentially languages stored in the database that are not supported by Postgres.**

### Additional information

```
select * from pg_catalog.pg_ts_config;
```

results in

```
  cfgname   | cfgnamespace | cfgowner | cfgparser
------------+--------------+----------+-----------
simple     |           11 |       10 |      3722
danish     |           11 |       10 |      3722
dutch      |           11 |       10 |      3722
english    |           11 |       10 |      3722
finnish    |           11 |       10 |      3722
french     |           11 |       10 |      3722
german     |           11 |       10 |      3722
hungarian  |           11 |       10 |      3722
italian    |           11 |       10 |      3722
norwegian  |           11 |       10 |      3722
portuguese |           11 |       10 |      3722
romanian   |           11 |       10 |      3722
russian    |           11 |       10 |      3722
spanish    |           11 |       10 |      3722
swedish    |           11 |       10 |      3722
turkish    |           11 |       10 |      3722
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As content_vector is already a tsvector, just build the index on it.  to_tsvector doesnt take a tsvector as it's second argument, not would it make sense to.